# serverless framework: Connecting additional resources (sqs) to api gateway (httpapi)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, aws-http-api

I have an httpapi apigateway, that I need to integrate directly to an sqs queue (directly).
I found this thread from over a year ago: https://forum.serverless.com/t/api-gateway-integration-with-sqs/7339
that suggested two plugins, but as mentioned in the thread- both seem outdated / unmaintained and do not support httpapi (only restapi)

Is there a different plugin available, or would this feature be supported natively in the new upcoming version 3 of serverless?
any other alternative ideas for accomplishing this?

Any help will be deeply appreciated